# Select records whose id does not appear in multiple tables

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have 3 tables. Two tables (par1, par1) both refer (child_id) to an id in the 3rd table (child).

I like to find orphans in the 3rd table, i.e. records that are not referenced by either of the other two tables.

If I had only once referencing table, I could write:

```
SELECT * FROM child WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT child_id FROM par1)
```

But how do I solve this for two referencing tables?

I'm using sqlite.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM child 
WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT child_id FROM par1) AND 
      id NOT IN (SELECT child_id FROM par2)
```

Comment: Ah, haha! I had thought about joined selects and other complicated things, but this is so simple, I am a bit embarrassed now :)

Comment: Wow, you're already a year on SO, and only now getting your first "best answer". Now I'm not feeling so bad for asking this question any more. Cheers! :)

Comment: Well... I had to answer some questions today to be able to post a question with embedded images: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16804510/how-to-avoid-data-loss-with-ef-model-first-database-schema-upgrade

Answer (score 1):

An alternative is to use LEFT OUTER JOIN:

```
SELECT child.*
FROM child LEFT OUTER JOIN par1 ON (child.id = par1.child_id)
           LEFT OUTER JOIN par2 ON (child.id = par2.child_id)
WHERE par1.child_id IS NULL AND par2.child_id IS NULL
```

Executing subqueries may or may not find the desired optimization paths in the SQLite index decision engine.

Comment: Thank you!  Exactly what I was looking for.